# I need help figuring out why my flip function only fires once and them seems to unbind. Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, flip, delay

I'm using 3 plugins here flip, delayed, and fancybox. I have it written so when you click the flip event fires, then delayed, then fancybox after the delay. I can't figure out why the flip is only working once but fancybox keeps working on subsequent clicks. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

   // First Home Page Popout Box
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#card-processing-link').live('click', function() {
       jQuery('#card-processing-box').flip({
              'direction' : 'lr',
               speed      : '300'
       });
   });    
   //Fancybox popout event
   jQuery('.card-processing-link').delayed('click', 400, function(){          
       jQuery(this).trigger('click').off().fancybox({
              'onStart'         : function(){
                                  jQuery('#card-processing-box').hide();
                                  jQuery('#card-processing-popout').show();
                                  },
              'transitionIn'   : 'elastic',
              'transitionOut'  : 'fadeOut',
              'speedIn'        : 300,
              'speedOut'       : 500,
              'width'          : '420',
              'height'         : 'auto',
              'scrolling'      : 'no',
              'centerOnScroll' : 'true',
              'overlayColor'   : 'transparent',
              'onClosed'       : function(){
                                 jQuery('#card-processing-popout').hide();
                                 jQuery('#card-processing-box').fadeIn();
                                           }            
       });
   });
</script>
```

live example at www.crexendo.com/store/4313892

Thanks!

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that you're removing all events and then initializing fancybox on it?

Comment: is card-processing-link an id or a class or both?

Comment: Kevin, how am I removing events?. Roasted I was trying to use a class and an id. I was meaning to change it back to just an id.

Comment: Also, you can see that i forgot to paste in my closing curly bracket, parenthesis and semicolon for the .ready function. Any more suggestions anyone?

Comment: .off() removes all events on the selected element.

Comment: Kevin, do you have any suggestions on how to stop the .trigger('click') from continuing to fire? That's why I used the .off(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.off()` then, seems your problem here/

Comment: I was thinking that as well but when I remove the .off() the .trigger('click') keeps firing over and over

Comment: Do you have any other ideas on how i can get the .trigger('click') from continuously firing?