# Can anyone help me figure out a way stop my .trigger('click') from continuously firing the fancybox event

Tags: jquery, fancybox, flip, delay

When you click I need it to flip, then delay, then popout with the fancybox. The only way I could figure out to get the fancybox to fire after a delay was with the delayed plugin and the  .trigger('click') to fire it after the delay. The problem is it keeps firing the .trigger('click') over and over continuously and I can't figure out a way to stop it without .off() which kills everything else. I would really appreciate some suggestions.

[Live example](http://www.crexendo.com/store/4313892)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

// First Home Page Popout Box
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#card-processing-link').live('click', function() {
       jQuery('#card-processing-box').flip({
              'direction' : 'lr',
               speed      : '300'
       });
   });    
   //Fancybox popout event
   jQuery('#card-processing-link').delayed('click', 400, function(){          
              jQuery(this).trigger('click').fancybox({
              'onStart'         : function(){
                                  jQuery('#card-processing-box').hide();
                                  jQuery('#card-processing-popout').show();
                                  },
              'transitionIn'   : 'elastic',
              'transitionOut'  : 'fadeOut',
              'speedIn'        : 300,
              'speedOut'       : 500,
              'width'          : '420',
              'height'         : 'auto',
              'scrolling'      : 'no',
              'centerOnScroll' : 'true',
              'overlayColor'   : 'transparent',
              'onClosed'       : function(){
                                 jQuery('#card-processing-popout').hide();
                                 jQuery('#card-processing-box').fadeIn();

                                           }            
       });
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: -1 : you already asked that question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/16966904/1055987 ... if it wasn't answered, maybe you need to be more specific but asking the same question again (which it's not encouraged) doesn't mean you will get help faster

Answer (score 1):

Why **do you want to trigger the click event** a , if you have already clicked it

`jQuery(this).fancybox({`

should be sufficient..

Otherwise you would end up in a infinite loop which would keep triggering the click event

You can use `setTimeout`  to delay the execution to a later time

```
jQuery.noConflict();

// First Home Page Popout Box
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#card-processing-link').live('click', function () {
        jQuery('#card-processing-box').flip({
            'direction': 'lr',
            speed: '300'
        });

        var $this = jQuery(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.fancybox({
                'onStart': function () {
                    jQuery('#card-processing-box').hide();
                    jQuery('#card-processing-popout').show();
                },
                    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut': 'fadeOut',
                    'speedIn': 300,
                    'speedOut': 500,
                    'width': '420',
                    'height': 'auto',
                    'scrolling': 'no',
                    'centerOnScroll': 'true',
                    'overlayColor': 'transparent',
                    'onClosed': function () {
                    jQuery('#card-processing-popout').hide();
                    jQuery('#card-processing-box').fadeIn();

                }
            });

        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried to do that exact thing but the .fancybox won't fire without the .trigger().

Comment: Why would a `fancybox` require a trigger

Comment: I just tried the setTimout suggestion and it's acting the same as using the .delayed without the .trigger('click'). For some reason the .fancybox won't fire.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the flip and just initialize the fancybox on click

Comment: Unfortunately no. Just tried it.

Comment: I think then maybe you are removing the events binding somewhere in your code.